# Getting german "umlaut" written correctly

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I guess this question has already been asked. but I just can't solved. 
I have a template in which I need to write in german. and I don't get the "Umlauts".

hier are the package that I'm used:

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                              
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}     % tried latin1  and ansinew and utf8 too
```

without any changes!

I'm working on TexWork , from MiKTeX2.9.

**UPDATE** 
Using the following :

```
    \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                    % deutsche Trennmuster
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                               % EC-Schriften, Trennstellen nach Umlauten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

causes the following:

```
......................
TextBlockOrigin set to 0pt x 0pt
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdfpages\pdfpages.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\eso-pic\eso-pic.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdfpages\pppdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\germbib\bibgerm.sty"
** Macros for german `BibTeX'ing added to Style Option `german' 20 Apr 1993 **
** idea and languages `german' and `USenglish' implemented by M. Wallmeier **
** Modified for LaTeX 2e and german.sty 2.5b by A. Scherer 1 Nov 1995 **
** Modified for ngerman.sty and babel.sty by H. Harders 21 August 2000 **)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\makeidx.sty")
Writing index file thesis3.idx
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\nomencl\nomencl.sty")
Writing nomenclature file thesis3.nlo
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.77  \pdfcompresslevel
                       =9
```

thanks for any help !

Comment: Inputenc `utf8` should work. Plesae post a MWE.

Comment: Since you ar working wth TexWorks, you probably have `utf8`.

Comment: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2656/wie-uberprufe-ich-die-standardeingabekodierung-in-meinem-editor

Comment: The default of TeXworks is indeed UTF8 but the OP uses a template and (without the original files) nobody knows the encoding of the files of the template. Old templates are often in ISO-Latin-1 and if you add new files with a modern editor (without changing the default encoding) the new files will be in UTF8 and then you have a problem. Templates are the evils door to you damnation!

Comment: Looking at what files are loaded by the templae, better drop it. See [LaTeX for scientific writing](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-Kompendium:_LaTeX_f%C3%BCr_wissenschaftiche_Arbeiten).

Comment: The template uses obsolete packages, e.g. [`germbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/germbib) that has been replaced by [`babelbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babelbib) decades ago. In our days I would even recommend to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: Undefined `\pdfcompresslevel` shouldn't be a problem of the file encoding but maybe of not using PDFLaTeX. But this is only speculation. Please show us a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), some information about how you compile it and maybe a link to the template. Or follow Johannes and drop the template (and delete the question).